# How do i have a different data for every account in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Excuse my lack of knowledge I'm  a complete newbie to Backend Development.

I've had this very simple model for testing

```
class Text(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.text
```

And with that I have this simple app that saves text through a form
[image]

and also I've made an entire basic login & sign up system with `UserCreationForm` and `AuthenticationForm` and with that I've made 3 different users.

With my lack of knowledge, I'm expecting to see a completely fresh app with no text saved to it when I log in with brand new user. But instead I just saw the same texts saved as every other users.

So my question is what Django method should I learn so that my text database is empty everytime I create a new user

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Text(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

now every text are related to user, on_delete you can search about it

Answer (score 0):

You can add a user foreign key in this table which will point user table
like this
user= models.Foreignkey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

and for showing the text you can query the Text.objects.filter(user=request.user)